# How to add/design a modal configuration pop up window to main JFrame in WindowBuilder?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, windowbuilder, gui-builder

All I want to do is have a JOptionPane pop up when the user clicks on a certain menu item.

The JOptionPane will show some basic configuration and then when the user clicks ok, the appropriate command will be run.

What I can't work out is how to do this in WindowBuilder.

The only way I can see is to create a separate class file but that seems like overkill.

How do I 'add' the JOptionPane so that I can see it and edit its design in WindowBuilder?

Comment: Do you know how to design a panel or container using Window Builder?  If so, you can use that for the container, then simply pass the container as the 2nd argument to the option pane `show...` methods.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I know the absolute basics of WindowBuilder, and have designed my basic main JFrame with the WYSIWYG. I don't know how to 'add' the JOptionPane to this so that I can edit/design that in the same WYSIWYG editor. I'm afraid haven't quite understood your suggestion either... could you elaborate? Thx!

Comment: *"could you elaborate?"*  Yeah sure.  What is it you don't understand about my suggestion?